# array_keys vs foreach in getting all keys

Tags: php, arrays

In getting all the keys of an array, which one has better performance ?
array_keys or foreach ?
I wonder if array_keys is a function that uses foreach loop or for loop, to get the keys.. (since foreach is a language construct), so foreach is better.

But, I'm not sure if array_keys use foreach loop to get the keys

So, which one is better

```
foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
    $pkey = ':' . $key;
    $placeholders[$pkey] = $value;
}
$value = array_keys($placeholders);
```

Or

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
    $pkey = ':' . $key;
    $placeholders[$pkey] = $value;
    $keys[] = $pkey;
}
```

Comment: After the edit it almost looks like you are using this array for prepared statements? You can do without those `:` as well, that saves you one extra loop FWIW

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yes, you're right. But, there must be `:` in the sql statement.So, I get the keys with `:` prepended to it. (with the keys are the column names). After that, I bind the value to the $placeholders

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Performance wise they are pretty much the same you can't really measure a difference, so simply put: ***Premature optimization is the root of all evil***.
Use whichever piece of code is most reliable and easiest to maintain, document and explain. When you're done writing your code, then start profiling it, *then* think about optimizing the major bottlenecks.

I run both scripts(on PHP 5.6) 10'000 times with a array of 100'000 elements and the average execution was about 0.025 sec.

script1:

```
<?php

    $arr = range(1, 100000);
    $keys = array_keys($arr);

?>
```

script2:

```
<?php

    $arr = range(1, 100000);

    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        $keys[] = $k;

?>
```

So from performance view there is no *real* difference between both methods.

But if you look at both scripts you will see that with the foreach loop you kinda write more code and also a *"useless"* loop, you can also see this that the method with the foreach loop then generates more opcode and makes almost double the amount of operations as the method with the `array_keys()`:

<sub>Also as pointed out in the [comments from @EliasVanOotegem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555889/array-keys-vs-foreach-in-getting-all-keys#comment47263050_29556153) it's not always a bad thing if a code generates more opcode to makes this clear here!</sub>

script1:

```
number of ops:  8
compiled vars:  !0 = $arr, !1 = $keys
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   SEND_VAL                                                 1
         1      SEND_VAL                                                 100000
         2      DO_FCALL                                      2  $0      'range'
         3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $0
   5     4      SEND_VAR                                                 !0
         5      DO_FCALL                                      1  $2      'array_keys'
         6      ASSIGN                                                   !1, $2
         7    > RETURN                                                   1
```

script2:

```
number of ops:  14
compiled vars:  !0 = $arr, !1 = $k, !2 = $v, !3 = $keys
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   SEND_VAL                                                 1
         1      SEND_VAL                                                 100000
         2      DO_FCALL                                      2  $0      'range'
         3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $0
   5     4    > FE_RESET                                         $2      !0, ->12
         5  > > FE_FETCH                                         $3      $2, ->12
         6  >   OP_DATA                                          ~5      
         7      ASSIGN                                                   !2, $3
         8      ASSIGN                                                   !1, ~5
   6     9      ASSIGN_DIM                                               !3
        10      OP_DATA                                                  !1, $8
        11    > JMP                                                      ->5
        12  >   SWITCH_FREE                                              $2
        13    > RETURN                                                   1
```

> I wonder if array_keys is a function that uses foreach loop or for loop

`array_keys()` doesn't use directly a foreach or for loop, but it also loops through the array. You can see this very clearly in the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L2877):

```
/* {{{ proto array array_keys(array input [, mixed search_value[, bool strict]])
   Return just the keys from the input array, optionally only for the specified search_value */
PHP_FUNCTION(array_keys)
{
     zval *input,                /* Input array */
         *search_value = NULL,  /* Value to search for */
        **entry,               /* An entry in the input array */
           res,                 /* Result of comparison */
          *new_val;             /* New value */
    int    add_key;             /* Flag to indicate whether a key should be added */
    zend_bool strict = 0;       /* do strict comparison */
    HashPosition pos;
    int (*is_equal_func)(zval *, zval *, zval * TSRMLS_DC) = is_equal_function;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a|zb", &input, &search_value, &strict) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (strict) {
        is_equal_func = is_identical_function;
    }

    /* Initialize return array */
    if (search_value != NULL) {
        array_init(return_value);
    } else {
        array_init_size(return_value, zend_hash_num_elements(Z_ARRVAL_P(input)));
    }
    add_key = 1;

    /* Go through input array and add keys to the return array */
    zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), &pos);
    while (zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), (void **)&entry, &pos) == SUCCESS) {
        if (search_value != NULL) {
            is_equal_func(&res, search_value, *entry TSRMLS_CC);
            add_key = zval_is_true(&res);
        }

        if (add_key) {
            MAKE_STD_ZVAL(new_val);
            zend_hash_get_current_key_zval_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), new_val, &pos);
            zend_hash_next_index_insert(Z_ARRVAL_P(return_value), &new_val, sizeof(zval *), NULL);
        }

        zend_hash_move_forward_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), &pos);
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

**Side Notes:**

- [php source code](https://github.com/php/php-src)
- [php source browser](http://lxr.php.net/)
- [VLD **v**ulcan **l**ogic **d**umper extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/vld) (for generation opcode)
- [online IDE with VLD extensions](http://3v4l.org/) (for smaller scripts)

Comment: One up for that beautiful `insider` story :)

Comment: `zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex` + `while (){zend_hash_move_forward_ex}` <-- looks like a loop to me, I don't see how `foreach` could be implemented that differently

Comment: just a short question: How did you get the compiler informations?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I wanted to show/say that `array_keys()` doesn't explicit call a "foreach"/"for" loop. e.g (pseudo code): `PHP_FUNCTION(array_keys){/* ... */ foreach($arr)}` (BTW: This is also why I wrote useless loop cursive and with quotes)

Comment: @JensSchulze It's an extension called `VLD` (**v**ulcan **l**ogic **d**umper): https://pecl.php.net/package/vld

Comment: @Rizier123: Point taken :-P. PS, a small nit-pick: if OP is running php >= 5.5, generating more opcodes isn't always a bad thing, compared to `DO_FCALL 'array_keys'`, which is a more expensive operation than some fetching and assigning (but going into that much detail might leave the OP confused)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ^ You got a point here :) Maybe I should include this in the answer, since maybe not every one know this!

Comment: @JensSchulze You're welcome! (If you need it for smaller scripts you can also use http://3v4l.org/ <- And there you can also look at the VLD output)

Comment: @Rizier123: +1 for this very complete answer, if you don't mind, I'll just add that old cliche _"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"_ as some sort of disclaimer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Don't mind at all :D (BTW: I like your link to the zend devzone about the hash tables)

Answer (score 4):

None of them, *(first one is in fact poor that it has a loop and then `array_keys` call too)*

Why do this?

```
foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
    $placeholders[$key] = $value;            // Useless loop
}
$keys = array_keys($placeholders);
```

When you can simply do

```
$keys = array_keys($value);   // if $value is your original array.
```

This is all you need. See example from **[PHP Manual](http://php.net/array_keys)**

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

The difference between `foreach` and `array_keys` in terms of speed will be so negligible that you will have to run a big scale test to even figure out the difference, Just that the `array_keys` way looks more neat (subjective).

Comment: Hmm.. Actually, the real code is that the $key is modified first in the loop, so the $key is not the same as the key of $value.. I'll edit my first post.. Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: @TerrySmith: If you modify the key, then a new zval is created (ie the original key is not modified. Inside the loop, you're working on a copy)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem So, the first one is the better, right ? [I have edited my code. Please take a look]

Comment: @TerrySmith: Depends on what you want, your PHP version and setup... I think that, for maintainability's sake, I'd actually opt for the second snippet, to avoid bugs in case `$placeholders` is not empty, and since I'm looping over the array anyway

Answer (score 2):

I run both versions 5x10'000'000 times with the following array:

```
$value = array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2','c'=>'3');
```

`first version` takes `22.61sec`

`second version` takes `20.15sec`

Comment: run it again. The first version is still slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should keep in mind:

1. Premature optimization is the root of all evil
2. If you want to test which of the two approaches is the fastest, write two scripts, run them a couple of thousand times, and compare the average time taken
3. `array_keys` does not use `foreach` as such, but `array_keys`, internally, iterates over the elements of the array in exactly the same way as `foreach` does
4. PHP arrays are hash tables, their implementation is well documented: [here, for example](http://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/#Heading5). How a basic array iteration works is explained with C examples, read through it, then look at PHP's source and find the `array_keys` implementation if you want to be absolutely, sure

TL;TR

It's entirely possible `foreach` is faster (no function call overhead), but it's a lot more verbose to write, *and* the performance difference between the two won't be the major bottleneck in your project.
Also note that, depending on your PHP version (and cached OP codes), the benchmark scripts might produce different results entirely

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand correctly what your asking, but i would use foreach to get the values of a array_key like so:

null, 'ZP9098' => null);

foreach(array_keys($mykeys) as $key){
    echo gettype($key)."\n"; }

?>